# Play video after the buffering was completed in background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I'm trying play a video stream with `MediaPlayer` in a new `Activity` after the buffering was completed in background. Why another `Activity`? It's a part of a video playback library, and the video has to overlay the user's app, no matter what layout is currently active.

My idea is to create a `MediaPlayer` object, start buffering (with `prepare` method) and after the buffering is complete start a new `Activity` with a `SurfaceView` for showing the video. In the new `Activity` I assign the `SurfaceHolder` of the `SurfaceView` to the `MediaPlayer` (with `setDisplay` method) and initiate playback, without success: I see the `SurfaceView` without the video playback.

I think, the problem is that the `MediaPlayer's` `prepare` method expects, that the `SurfaceHolder` was set with the `setDisplay` method before it.

Any ideas to get this setup working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after weeks of trying and futher investigation, here is the answer:

With the current versions of Android SDK there is no way to preload a video in background with the `VideoView` or `MediaPlayer` due to the fact that the latter needs a created Surface to start preloading. Thus, your `VideoView` or your `MediaPlayer` has to be (temporary) a visible part of the application's layout before you can start preloading (with `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()`). This solution requires injecting of these `Views` in the user's layout or starting a temporary Activity to get the Surface initialized, which is too invasive for my subject (video SDK).

If you requirement is to show a video without letting the user wait for a completed buffering and you dont have the control about the application's layout, I would suggest to store the complete video to the sd-card and start the playback afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Start a Async task and inside the body of method doinBackground() start a   onBuffering listener ,,, and you can store the data in a cache ,, and then can play the video.
may be this can perform your required task.

Comment: The problem is the playback, not with the buffering. The MediaPlayer starts async buffering by calling `prepareAsync` method. I use the `OnPreparedListener` to check if the buffering was complete.

Answer (score 0):

what i did i tell you and it worked for me ,

made a class extends async and implements  OnPrepared Listener, then in method

```
doinbackgroung(){
Display display =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
video_view.setOnPreparedListener(this);
video_view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path)); 
return null;
}
```

and afterwards  in onPrepared()
just video_view.start();

You can also implement onVideoSizeChangedListener if you want the video both in landscape an dportrait mode to play good.. this will work it seems

Comment: Sorry, but I dont see, how this answer is related to my question. What should be done with `display`?

Comment: videoview is your display , videoView.start() will start the display , what else do you need to display